# Is there a difference between laptop and desktop RAM?

Tags: laptop, memory

Looking to upgrade my Acer laptop, and from what I've researched, I can swap out a 1x2GB module with a max of 1x8 GB module of DDR3 running at 16000mhz. I've found a listing on Amazon for the exact some module but the product states it is a Desktop RAM

Is it okay to use Desktop RAM in laptop RAM?  If not, what should I be looking for in terms of RAM for a laptop?

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://superuser.com/questions/105422/can-i-use-laptop-ram-in-a-desktop) and [this](http://superuser.com/questions/660840/difference-between-ddr3-sdram-and-ddr3-sodimm-for-laptop) etc.

Comment: @user55325 Doesn't your first question ask the opposite of this question?

Comment: Yes, but the answer is the same...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Desktop memory is a different size and shape and will not fit in a laptop. What you want is a 204-pin SODIMM (small-outline DIMM).

Comment: Thanks a bunch. So basically any laptop RAM will do? or are there specific sizes with different brands of laptops?

Comment: Any DDR3 SODIMM should work. Check with your manufacturer's documentation for potential electrical/software incompatibility, but any 204-pin SODIMM will fit, at least.